# AWS - Fatal Error (backing_store) != nullptr

Tags: amazon-web-services, jira, atlassian-forge, amazon-location-service

So basically I'm trying to use the AWS Location API to get the coordinates of a given address in an Atlassian Forge Environment. If I read it right, I should use the GetPlaceCommand function, so I tried to use it in my code, first of all I don't really get IndexName and PlaceId, can I just write eu-central-1 in the IndexName or what should I put in there, and in PlaceId I think I should just put the address, I hope that's right so far. Then we get to my Error, as soon as forge gets to snapshotting the code, it throws an error about a check failed with the backing_store, whatever that means, or what it is essentially and why it shouldn't be a nullpointer. Is there something I forgot about in my Code or did I do something wrong, or is it a bug by Amazon?

This is my Code:

```
const AmazonApp = () => {
    useEffect(async () => {
        const client = new AWS.Location({ region: "eu-central-1" });
        const input = {
            // GetPlaceRequest
            IndexName: address.replace(" ", "-"), // required
            PlaceId: address, // required
            Key: API_KEY
        };
  
        const command = new AWS.GetPlaceCommand(input);
        const response = await client.send(command);
        console.log(response);
    }, []);
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Text>Hello world!</Text>
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

And this is my Error:

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: (backing_store) != nullptr.
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x40007f96b0
 1: 0xaa8641  [node]
 2: 0x1a48174 V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [node]
 3: 0x1110e3c bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
 4: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
 5: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
 6: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
 7: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
 8: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
 9: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
10: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
11: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
12: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
13: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
14: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
15: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
16: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
17: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
18: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
19: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
20: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
21: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
22: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
23: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
24: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
25: 0x1110d25 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
26: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
27: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
28: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
29: 0x1110d25 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
30: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
31: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
32: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
33: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
34: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
35: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
36: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
37: 0x1110d25 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
38: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
39: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
40: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
41: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
42: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
43: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
44: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
45: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
46: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
47: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
48: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
49: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
50: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
51: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
52: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
53: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
54: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
55: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
56: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
57: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
58: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
59: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
60: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
61: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
62: 0x1111126 v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadObject(v8::internal::SnapshotSpace) [node]
63: 0x1110996 bool v8::internal::Deserializer::ReadData<v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::FullMaybeObjectSlot, v8::internal::SnapshotSpace, unsigned long) [node]
64: 0x110b4b4 v8::internal::ContextDeserializer::Deserialize(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSGlobalProxy>, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback) [node]
65: 0x110bcc4 v8::internal::ContextDeserializer::DeserializeContext(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::SnapshotData const*, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSGlobalProxy>, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback) [node]
66: 0x11320ba v8::internal::Snapshot::NewContextFromSnapshot(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSGlobalProxy>, unsigned long, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback) [node]
67: 0xe33258 v8::internal::Genesis::Genesis(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::JSGlobalProxy>, v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate>, unsigned long, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback, v8::MicrotaskQueue*) [node]
68: 0xe33608 v8::internal::Bootstrapper::CreateEnvironment(v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::JSGlobalProxy>, v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate>, v8::ExtensionConfiguration*, unsigned long, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback, v8::MicrotaskQueue*) [node]
69: 0xbcff3e v8::NewContext(v8::Isolate*, v8::ExtensionConfiguration*, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::ObjectTemplate>, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value>, unsigned long, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback, v8::MicrotaskQueue*) [node]
70: 0xbd0554 v8::Context::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::ExtensionConfiguration*, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::ObjectTemplate>, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value>, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback, v8::MicrotaskQueue*) [node]
71: 0x402c312494 ivm::IsolateEnvironment::NewContext() [/tunnel/node_modules/@forge/isolated-vm/build/Release/isolated_vm.node]
72: 0x402c314429 ivm::IsolateEnvironment::IsolateCtor(unsigned long, std::shared_ptr<v8::BackingStore>, unsigned long) [/tunnel/node_modules/@forge/isolated-vm/build/Release/isolated_vm.node]
73: 0x402c33b171 ivm::IsolateHandle::New(v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>) [/tunnel/node_modules/@forge/isolated-vm/build/Release/isolated_vm.node]
74: 0x402c340a31 ivm::ConstructorFunction<std::unique_ptr<ivm::ClassHandle, std::default_delete<ivm::ClassHandle> > (*)(v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>), &ivm::IsolateHandle::New>::Entry(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/tunnel/node_modules/@forge/isolated-vm/build/Release/isolated_vm.node]
75: 0xc27795  [node]
76: 0xc27d9f  [node]
77: 0xc283c6 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
78: 0x1449459  [node]
qemu: uncaught target signal 4 (Illegal instruction) - core dumped
```